# How can I set up a function so it's called rather than inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was given the following code:

accept

Something like this:

```
$("input[id^='position_']").change(function() {
    //get the value of the input field marked with "position_x"
    var posX = $(this).val();
    var idArr = $(this).attr("id");
    var idTmp = idArr.split("_");
    var id = idTmp[1];
        var divX = $("div[id='"+id+"']").html();    
    make an ajax call passing the two parameters.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "your_url",
        data: "pos_x="+posX+"&div_x="+divX,
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

I like to keep things simple. Is there a way that I can split this code into a function and then have the function be called here: `$("input[id^='position_']").change(function() {`

Also the function seems kind of complex. What I need is for when a user clicks an input field then I will get the value of that field along with the value of another field in the same row and then send to Ajax.

Can anyone see a way I could simplify this?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized based on the second portion of the question; it seems unlikely to be "generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what do you mean "simplify". It does what it has to be. If you mean making code shorter below is a version of your code. It's harder to read but does same work. And you can see how to use named function instead of anonymous function too.

```
$("input[id^='position_']").change(doTheMagic);

function doTheMagic() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "your_url",
        data: "pos_x=" + $(this).val() + "&div_x=" + $("div[id='" + $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1] + "']").html(),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks. I had the way I was trying to define the function incorrect. Now it works okay after u helped me out.

Comment: You're welcome. If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).